# How can I use "other" in singular and plural?

Tags: differences

What is the difference between other and another?
I know that another is only for singular and other can be used in singular or plural. Can you give some examples?

Comment: Hi Octavio Perez, Welcome to EL&U, I think this is a very trivial question for this site, it doesn't hurt to post it here but it would be better to ask the same at our sister community English Language Learners(http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Other* is more general, as it often is when it refers to two or more things, concepts or people; whereas *another* is more specific and it often refers to just one thing, concept, or person.

Some uses of *other*:

> - Do we have any other ideas?
> - I think we should consider other candidates.
> - Are you in favor of making other attempts?
> - When we have other options, we will consider doing it. [Here the word *it* assumes there is one action but perhaps many ways of performing the action. For example, *it* could mean raising money for a specific purpose, but there are numerous ways of (or options for) raising money.]

Some uses of *another*:

> - Do we have another idea?
> - I think we should consider another candidate.
> - Are you in favor of another attempt?
> - When we have another option, we will consider doing it. [Here the use of *it* refers to just the next option to be considered, not one of many other options, especially if other options were considered previously but were rejected.]